# iOS 16 exitFullScreenAnimated not working

Tags: ios, swift

On my iPhone 6s running iOS 15.7.7, when I do `videoViewController.perform(NSSelectorFromString("exitFullScreenAnimated:completionHandler:"), with: animated, with: nil)`, the app behaves as expected and correctly calls this `func playerViewController(_ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController ...)` delegate function.

However, on my iPhone 12 Pro running iOS 16.6.1, the selector doesn't correctly exit, and the same delegate method also doesn't get called.

I put print statements in the delegate function to confirm that it does get called on iOS 15.7.7, but not on iOs 16.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the call to the selector, I did the following:

`videoViewController.dismiss(animated: true)`

Now exiting on rotation and on manually tapping the exit button work for both iOS 15 and 16 devices.